# get space separated fields in other comma separated fields ( loop?)

Tags: php, explode

first question answered very quickly, thanks to all.

here is the issue, for a given string..

```
$str= "name1 surname2, name2 midname2 surname2";
```

to make things more clear, there is two persons, one has two values(name, surname) while other has midname too. so, I want to get all them separate while knowing which name belongs to which person, like;

```
foreach ($persons as person){
   if( person has midname){
      $value1 ="name"; $value2= "midname"; $value3="surname"}
    else
    $value1="name"; $value2="surname"   
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = str_replace(',', '', $str);
$arr = explode(' ', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you want to do is split the string using either spaces or commas as delimiters you can use preg_split:

```
$str = "field1 field2 field3, field4 field5, field6";

$v = preg_split("/[\s,]+/", $str);

var_dump($v);
```

And you'll get this:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "field1"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "field2"
  [2]=>
  string(6) "field3"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "field4"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "field5"
  [5]=>
  string(6) "field6"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

i would normalize the separater charater first then explode() on the common separator..

```
# replace spaces with commas:
$str = str_replace( ' ', ',', $str );
# replace the 'doubled commas' with single commas:
$str = str_replace( ',,', ',', $str );
# now you have normalized input:
print_r( explode(',', $str ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $str = "field1 field2 field3, field4 field5, field6   field7 , field8";

    // even works on more than one space or a comma surrounded by spaces.
    $v = preg_split("~\s*,\s*|\s+~", $str);

    var_dump($v);
?>
```

output

```
array
  0 => string 'field1' (length=6)
  1 => string 'field2' (length=6)
  2 => string 'field3' (length=6)
  3 => string 'field4' (length=6)
  4 => string 'field5' (length=6)
  5 => string 'field6' (length=6)
```